# Finding centre of mass of tensor (tensorflow)

Tags: python, tensorflow, mean

Is there an efficient way to find the centre of mass of a tensor? I'm working with N stacked volumes (Nx64x64x64) and would like to obtain an Nx3 tensor with the x,y,z position of the centre of mass of each 64x64x64 volume

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Following the formula, you should just need to multiply each coordinate by the corresponding mass, sum everything and divide by the total mass:

```
import tensorflow as tf

# Input volumes
volumes = tf.placeholder(tf.float32, [None, 64, 64, 64])
# Make array of coordinates (each row contains three coordinates)
ii, jj, kk = tf.meshgrid(tf.range(64), tf.range(64), tf.range(64), indexing='ij')
coords = tf.stack([tf.reshape(ii, (-1,)), tf.reshape(jj, (-1,)), tf.reshape(kk, (-1,))], axis=-1)
coords = tf.cast(coords, tf.float32)
# Rearrange input into one vector per volume
volumes_flat = tf.reshape(volumes, [-1, 64 * 64 * 64, 1])
# Compute total mass for each volume
total_mass = tf.reduce_sum(volumes_flat, axis=1)
# Compute centre of mass
centre_of_mass = tf.reduce_sum(volumes_flat * coords, axis=1) / total_mass
```

Comment: You are a life saver! I'm new to tensorflow so I sometimes find it difficult to have an intuitive way to figure stuff like this out. Tank you!

Answer (score 0):

This is a perfect use case for `numpy.apply_over_axes`:

```
my_tensor = np.apply_over_axes( np.mean, my_tensor, (1,2,3))
```

This will return an array of shape `(N,1,1,1)` with the average along each axis.

Comment: thanks for your input. I need however to only use tensorflow and can't use for loops

Comment: updated with something built in numpy that does not require explicit for loops =)

Comment: thanks again for the help! I am however looking for the location of the centre of mass. Your function is returning me the average value of each volume