# Complex indexing without loop

Tags: python-3.x, numpy, indexing, mean

I have an array that has Nx5 dimensions. The last 3 dimensions are the x, y, and z of different volumes. These are then packed into the other two dimensions. For example:

```
[[0 0 x0 y0 z0],
[0 0 x1 y1 z1],
[0 0 x2 y2 z2],
[0 1 x3 y3 z3],
[0 1 x4 y4 z4],
[1 0 x5 y5 z5],
[1 0 x6 y6 z6],
[1 1 x7 y7 z7],
[1 1 x8 y8 z8],
[2 0 x9 y9 z9],
[2 0 x10 y10 z10],
[2 0 x11 y11 z11],
[2 1 x12 y12 z12]]
```

The number of volumes for each of the first two dimensions varies every time. I wanto to calculate the mean of x, y, and z for each volume in each dimension. This should result in something like this:

```
[[0 0 xmean0 ymean0 zmean0],
[0 1 xmean1 ymean1 zmean1],
[1 0 xmean2 ymean2 zmean2],
[1 1 xmean3 ymean3 zmean3]]
[2 0 xmean4 ymean4 zmean4],
[2 1 xmean5 ymean5 zmean5]]
```

In other words, it should have the mean for each combination of the first to elements. I cannot use loops for this, only numpy and/or tensorflow.

Answer (score 1):

We will assume the input array is `a`.

**Approach #1 :** With `bincount` -

```
unq_comb,ids, w = np.unique(a[:,:2], axis=0, return_inverse=1, return_counts=1)
out = np.empty((len(unq_comb),5))
out[:,:2] = unq_comb
for i in [2,3,4]:
    out[:,i] = np.bincount(ids, a[:,i])/w
```

**Approach #2 :** With `sorting` -

```
sidx = np.lexsort(a[:,:2].T)
b = a[sidx]
idx = np.flatnonzero(np.r_[True,(b[:-1,:2] != b[1:,:2]).any(1),True])
w = np.diff(idx)[:,None].astype(float)
out = np.empty((len(unq_comb),5))
out[:,:2] = b[idx[:-1],:2]
out[:,2:] = np.add.reduceat(b[:,2:], idx[:-1], axis=0)/w
```

Comment: Thanks for the replies! Sadly I can't use the first one because I can't use loops. 
The second one works well, but I'm having some trouble implementing it into tensorflow due to lexsort :S Any advice?

Comment: @FelipeMoser Don't be hung up on not using loops. Bincount is very efficient and we are just looping for three iterations there.

Comment: Thanks for the kick reply. Sadly, it's part of the constraints I have for this particular project :(

Comment: Hey! Sadly no, in the end I went with another solution for my specific problem which you can find here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51724450/finding-centre-of-mass-of-tensor-tensorflow

Comment: @FelipeMoser That looks like an entirely different question. But, good you have your solution somehow.

Comment: Yes it is. The question here was to solve a different approach to that problem. But thanks for your help!